# Alibaba cloud - video streaming

Tags: php, video-streaming, laravel-5.4, alibaba-cloud

I want to use video on demand service of Alibaba cloud for video streaming.
video on demand makes different resolution videos from uploaded videos for data streaming.
For that, I am using https://github.com/aliyun/aliyun-openapi-php-sdk.
Now problem is that I don't know how to upload video in a **video on demand panel** via code. I have checked in a https://github.com/aliyun/aliyun-openapi-php-sdk/blob/master/aliyun-php-sdk-vod/vod/Request/V20170321/CreateUploadVideoRequest.php but haven't found field or parameter which is used to upload video. If any other SDK or code is there then please let me know. Even any document of a code or snippet is also appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Sample code snippet could be found here (in Simplified Chinese though):  https://help.aliyun.com/document_detail/61069.html

```
<?php
include_once './aliyun-php-sdk/aliyun-php-sdk-core/Config.php'; //source php and aliyun-php-sdk in same directory
use vod\Request\V20170321 as vod;
function init_vod_client($accessKeyId, $accessKeySecret) {
    $regionId = 'cn-shanghai';  
    $profile = DefaultProfile::getProfile($regionId, $accessKeyId, $accessKeySecret);
    return new DefaultAcsClient($profile);
}
function create_upload_video($client) {
    $request = new vod\CreateUploadVideoRequest();
    $request->setTitle("VideoTitle");               // Video Title (Mandatory)
    $request->setFileName("filename.mov");          // Source document file name with file extension (Mandatory)
    $request->setDescription("Video Description");  // Video Description (Optional)
    $request->setCoverURL("http://img.alicdn.com/tps/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-700-700.png"); // Custom video coverpage (Optional)
    $request->setTags("Tag1,Tag2");                 // Video tags, separated by commas (Optional)
    $request->setAcceptFormat('JSON');
    return $client->getAcsResponse($request);
}
try {
    $client = init_vod_client('<AccessKeyId>', '<AccessKeySecret>');
    $uploadInfo = create_upload_video($client);
    var_dump($uploadInfo);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print $e->getMessage()."\n";
}
?>
```

There is also a demo for using OSS SDK to upload video available in https://help.aliyun.com/document_detail/61388.html (also in Simplified Chinese)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Please find the code snippet.

```
<?php
require_once './aliyun-php-sdk/aliyun-php-sdk-core/Config.php';    
require_once './aliyun-php-sdk/aliyun-oss-php-sdk-2.2.4/autoload.php';

use vod\Request\V20170321 as vod;
use OSS\OssClient;
use OSS\Core\OssException;


function init_vod_client($accessKeyId, $accessKeySecret) {
    $regionId = 'cn-shanghai'; 
    $profile = DefaultProfile::getProfile($regionId, $accessKeyId, $accessKeySecret);
    return new DefaultAcsClient($profile);
}


function create_upload_video($vodClient) {
    $request = new vod\CreateUploadVideoRequest();

    $request->setTitle("Movie");        
    $request->setFileName("elephant.mov"); 

    $request->setDescription("It is about elephant"); 
    $request->setCoverURL("http://img.alicdn.com/tps/TB1qnJ1PVXXXXXCXXXXXXXXXXXX-700-700.png"); 
    $request->setTags("forest,elephant"); 

    return $vodClient->getAcsResponse($request);
}

function refresh_upload_video($vodClient, $videoId) {
    $request = new vod\RefreshUploadVideoRequest();
    $request->setVideoId($videoId);
    return $vodClient->getAcsResponse($request);
}

function init_oss_client($uploadAuth, $uploadAddress) {
    $ossClient = new OssClient($uploadAuth['AccessKeyId'], $uploadAuth['AccessKeySecret'], $uploadAddress['Endpoint'], 
        false, $uploadAuth['SecurityToken']);
    $ossClient->setTimeout(86400*7);    
    $ossClient->setConnectTimeout(10);  
    return $ossClient;
}


function upload_local_file($ossClient, $uploadAddress, $localFile) {
    return $ossClient->uploadFile($uploadAddress['Bucket'], $uploadAddress['FileName'], $localFile);
}


function multipart_upload_file($ossClient, $uploadAddress, $localFile) {
    return $ossClient->multiuploadFile($uploadAddress['Bucket'], $uploadAddress['FileName'], $localFile);
}

$accessKeyId = '<AccessKeyId>';
$accessKeySecret = '<AccessKeySecret>';           
$localFile = '/Users/yours/Video/testVideo.flv';   

try {

    $vodClient = init_vod_client($accessKeyId, $accessKeySecret);
    $createRes = create_upload_video($vodClient);

    $videoId = $createRes->VideoId;
    $uploadAddress = json_decode(base64_decode($createRes->UploadAddress), true);
    $uploadAuth = json_decode(base64_decode($createRes->UploadAuth), true);


    $ossClient = init_oss_client($uploadAuth, $uploadAddress);


    //$result = upload_local_file($ossClient, $uploadAddress, $localFile);
    $result = multipart_upload_file($ossClient, $uploadAddress, $localFile);
    printf("Succeed, VideoId: %s", $videoId);

} catch (Exception $e) {
    // var_dump($e);
    printf("Failed, ErrorMessage: %s", $e->getMessage());
}
```

For more details, Please have a look at the [official documentation](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/61388.htm?spm=a2c63.l28256.b99.222.12722839VrNx2L)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the newest code update on 202105 for you.
the guide link as below:

https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/100976.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.879954.13.330a12fcc5cLMD#task-1995280

```
<? php
/**
 * Created by Aliyun ApsaraVideo VOD.
 */
require_once dirname(__DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'voduploadsdk' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Autoloader.php';
date_default_timezone_set('PRC');
// Test the upload of an on-premises video.
function testUploadLocalVideo($accessKeyId, $accessKeySecret, $filePath)
{
    try {
        $uploader = new AliyunVodUploader($accessKeyId, $accessKeySecret);
        $uploadVideoRequest = new UploadVideoRequest($filePath, 'testUploadLocalVideo via PHP-SDK');
        //$uploadVideoRequest->setCateId(1);
        //$uploadVideoRequest->setCoverURL("http://xxxx.jpg");
        //$uploadVideoRequest->setTags('test1,test2');
        //$uploadVideoRequest->setStorageLocation('outin-xx.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com');
        //$uploadVideoRequest->setTemplateGroupId('6ae347b0140181ad371d197ebe289326');
        $userData = array(
            "MessageCallback"=>array("CallbackURL"=>"https://demo.sample.com/ProcessMessageCallback"),
            "Extend"=>array("localId"=>"xxx", "test"=>"www")
        );
        $uploadVideoRequest->setUserData(json_encode($userData));
        $res = $uploader->uploadLocalVideo($uploadVideoRequest);
        print_r($res);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        printf("testUploadLocalVideo Failed, ErrorMessage: %s\n Location: %s %s\n Trace: %s\n",
            $e->getMessage(), $e->getFile(), $e->getLine(), $e->getTraceAsString());
    }
}
// Tests the upload of an online video.
function testUploadWebVideo($accessKeyId, $accessKeySecret, $fileURL)
{
    try {
        $uploader = new AliyunVodUploader($accessKeyId, $accessKeySecret);
        $uploadVideoRequest = new UploadVideoRequest($fileURL, 'testUploadWebVideo via PHP-SDK');
        $res = $uploader->uploadWebVideo($uploadVideoRequest);
        print_r($res);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        printf("testUploadWebVideo Failed, ErrorMessage: %s\n Location: %s %s\n Trace: %s\n",
            $e->getMessage(), $e->getFile(), $e->getLine(), $e->getTraceAsString());
    }
}
// Test the upload of an on-premises M3U8 video.
function testUploadLocalM3u8($accessKeyId, $accessKeySecret, $m3u8FilePath)
{
    try {
        $uploader = new AliyunVodUploader($accessKeyId, $accessKeySecret);
        $uploadVideoRequest = new UploadVideoRequest($m3u8FilePath, 'testUploadLocalM3u8 via PHP-SDK');
        // Call the method for parsing the M3U8 playlist to obtain the URLs of parts. If the parsing result is invalid, manually assemble the URLs of parts. By default, the part files and M3U8 files are stored in the same directory.
        $sliceFiles = $uploader->parseM3u8File($m3u8FilePath);
        //print_r($sliceFiles);
        $res = $uploader->uploadLocalM3u8($uploadVideoRequest, $sliceFiles);
        print_r($res);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        printf("testUploadLocalM3u8 Failed, ErrorMessage: %s\n Location: %s %s\n Trace: %s\n",
            $e->getMessage(), $e->getFile(), $e->getLine(), $e->getTraceAsString());
    }
}
// Test the upload of an online M3U8 video.
function testUploadWebM3u8($accessKeyId, $accessKeySecret, $m3u8FileUrl)
{
    try {
        $uploader = new AliyunVodUploader($accessKeyId, $accessKeySecret);
        $uploadVideoRequest = new UploadVideoRequest($m3u8FileUrl, 'testUploadWebM3u8 via PHP-SDK');
        // Call the method for parsing the M3U8 playlist to obtain the URLs of parts. If the parsing result is invalid, manually assemble the URLs of parts. By default, the part files and M3U8 files are stored in the same directory.
        $sliceFileUrls = $uploader->parseM3u8File($m3u8FileUrl);
        //print_r($sliceFileUrls);
        $res = $uploader->uploadWebM3u8($uploadVideoRequest, $sliceFileUrls);
        print_r($res);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        printf("testUploadWebM3u8 Failed, ErrorMessage: %s\n Location: %s %s\n Trace: %s\n",
            $e->getMessage(), $e->getFile(), $e->getLine(), $e->getTraceAsString());
    }
}
####   Run the test code.   ####
$accessKeyId = '<AccessKeyId>';
$accessKeySecret = '<AccessKeySecret>';
//$localFilePath = 'C:\test\sample.mp4';
$localFilePath = '/opt/video/sample.mp4';
//testUploadLocalVideo($accessKeyId, $accessKeySecret, $localFilePath);
$webFileURL = 'http://vod-test1.cn-shanghai.aliyuncs.com/b55b904bc612463b812990b7c8cc95c8/daa30814c0c340cf8199926f78aa5c0e-a0bc05ba62c3e95cc672e88b828148c9-ld.mp4?auth_key=1608774986-0-0-c56acd302bea0c331370d8ed686502fe';
testUploadWebVideo($accessKeyId, $accessKeySecret, $webFileURL);
$localM3u8FilePath = '/opt/video/m3u8/sample.m3u8';
//testUploadLocalM3u8($accessKeyId, $accessKeySecret, $localM3u8FilePath);
$webM3u8FileURL = 'http://vod-test1.cn-shanghai.aliyuncs.com/b55b904bc612463b812990b7c8cc95c8/daa30814c0c340cf8199926f78aa5c0e-195a25af366b5edae324c47e99a03f04-ld.m3u8?auth_key=1608775606-0-0-9fb038deaecd009dadd86721c5855629';
//testUploadWebM3u8($accessKeyId, $accessKeySecret, $webM3u8FileURL);
```